# Android changing private static final field using Java Reflection?

Tags: android

I want to set "NO_CACHE" to be newValue. Here is my code:

```
static void setFinalStatic(Object newValue) throws Exception
{
    Field field = CacheManager.class.getDeclaredField("NO_CACHE");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Field modifiersField=Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
    modifiersField.setInt(field,field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
    field.set(null, newValue);
}
```

But running this code on Android produces the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: modifiers
```

I find `modifiers` is a field in the `Field` class in Java, but it is not a field in the `Field` class on Android.

This is Java `Field` class code:

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.java.html

This is Android `Field` class code:

http://www.oschina.net/code/explore/android-2.2-froyo/java/lang/reflect/Field.java

The above code in Java can work, but it does not work on the Android platform.

How do I fix this?

Comment: android.webkit.CacheManager

Comment: How would this work outside of Android, if it is an Android-only class?

Comment: The CacheManager class code:   http://www.oschina.net/code/explore/android-2.2-froyo/android/webkit/CacheManager.java

Comment: I mean, how/why would you use it outside Android? You say this works in Java, but, this class has no field `modifiers` to begin with. I don't see how it would ever work.

Comment: Maybe my thinking is wrong.

Answer (score 7):

I have tried the solutions above and get the correct way to modify static and final field in Android,here is the code works in Android 7.0

```
Field booleanField = Boolean.class.getField("FALSE");
booleanField.setAccessible(true);
Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("accessFlags");
modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
modifiersField.setInt(field,field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
booleanField.set(null, true);
```

Comment: when android 30, it not work

Answer (score 3):

Android actually doesn't use JDK source code. It's something very alike but not the same.

In Java, modifiers are of type `java.lang.reflection.Field`, but in Android there is no such type. Android implemented a system which uses an integer and the name of the Field to validate it's modifiers, by calling a native method.

I think a `private static final` field will have `slot`-1 and a private field will have the value 3. If you wish to change a `private static final` field, just change the `slot` to 3 before setting the value.

```
Field booleanField = Boolean.class.getField("FALSE");
booleanField.setAccessible(true);

Field slotField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("slot");
slotField.setAccessible(true);
slotField.set(booleanField, 3);

booleanField.set(Boolean.FALSE, true);
```

Comment: The field in Android is called `accessFlags` not `slot` and not `modifiers `